# Configure Apache Qpid dispatch router to send undelivered action - redirect

Tags: amqp, qpid

How i can configure Apache Qpid to send AMQP 1.0 connection-level redirect and link-level redirect to a client that are connected or trying to connect to the dispatcher.

Comment: Apache Qpid has multiple components.  Is this question regarding the Qpid Dispatch message router?

If so, I don't think it currently has the ability to configure redirects.  I went looking to see if there's already an RFE for it, and I found one that perhaps you raised? https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DISPATCH-1632

Comment: After some research and also discussion with Enmasse community(https://enmasse.io/), i come to the conclusion that Qpid Dispatch router don't support this. And I posted the issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DISPATCH-1632.